# error in building a qt make project using qt

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I get this error while building my qt project on arch linux

```
make[1]: /opt/qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake: Command not found
```

what could be the problem ?

Comment: Either you do not have qmake installed or it is not in your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you install qt?
I am not used to arch. i think that the packet manages is pacman
you should have something like:

```
pacman -S qt5-base
```

as you can see from the doc this package contains qmake:
https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qt5-base/

Since as you said this is installed probably the path you try to use is the wrong. I think you should use:

```
/usr/bin/qmake-qt5
```

Comment: Why do you assume he's running Arch ?

Comment: I'm actually running Arch

Comment: well... first line in his question

Comment: @Stefano Ops, sorry :)

Comment: try again... it is not install but -S

Comment: Get a usable distribution! :)

Comment: where should I set this /usr/bin/qmake-qt5

Comment: if you just run /usr/bin/qmake-qt5 does it run? i do not know what are you doing... are you using qtCreator or do you have you own makefile?

Comment: well. thank you have just to configure correctly your Qt creator soi that it loads the tools from the correct path. here the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html